# Did I Commit Gay Zina?

Tags: zina

Salam alaikum brothers and sisters. I have this very huge problem that I feel extremely guilty about. I invited my friend to my house and I had a small sexual lust for grabbing his butt. I did it once and claimed that it was an accident. He forgot about it. I have ZERO sexual attraction to him anymore and I really want to repent I feel extremely guilty. What should I do? Was this Zina in any way? Is their a punishment for this in life? How can I repent?

P.S: I am straight 100% now and I am 13.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu Alaikum, brother.
you should know that having sexual lust, as you call it, or even going close to it with a female that isn't your wife is haram. not to talk of having it with a man. it is totally prohibited and you have committed a very big sin brother.
But fortunately, Allah is The all-forgiving and The most merciful. Repent and promise never to go back to committing such thing.
ma'assalaam.

Comment: exactly. This youth is told to "try everything out" and unfortunately some of our younger brothers and sisters fall for it.